How to remove/limit Editor accounts privileges, to prevent them from deleting media and pages created by Admin
How can I remove (or edit) Editor account privilege's, to prevent Editor accounts from making any changes to things Admin accounts upload or create?
For instance,

Prevent Editors from deleting/editing Admin's uploaded media
Prevent Editors from deleting/editing Admin's pages
Prevent Editors from deleting/editing Admin's posts

As a plus, the cherry on top, can it be done without plugins?

wordpress core doesn't have configuration for that then you need a plugin, either a existent or a plugin you create yourself.
